# Need help showing that the intervals $[a,b]+[c,d]=[a+c,b+d]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Define $$A+B=\{x+y\mid x\in A,\ y\in B\}$$

Prove: $[a,b]+[c,d]=[a+c,b+d]$. Im pretty sure that I have the forward containment but I need help showing that $$[a+c,b+d]\subset[a,b]+[c,d].$$ Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are $[a,b]$ supposed to be $\{x| a \le x \le b\}$?

Comment: @fleablood yeah they are just arbitrary intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x \in [a+c,b+d]$ then $a+c \le x \le b+d$.

$a \le x-c \le b+(d-c)$

Let $k = \min (x-c, b)$ so $a \le x-c\le k$ so $a \le k$ and $k \le b$ so $k\in [a,b]$.

Let $j = x-k$.  If $k = x-c$ then $j = c \in [c,d]$.  If $k = b$ then $j=x-b$ and $a+c \le x \le b+d$ so $a+c-b \le x-b=j < d$ ane $k \le x-c$ so $j= x-k \ge x-(x-c)= c$ so $j \in [c,d]$.

As $x = k+ j$ and $k \in [a,b]$ and $j\in [c,d]$ so $x \in [a,b] +[c,d]$.